# How to load a fragment on button click in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Below is a picture of a "practice" application that I am working on.
I want to swipe the fragment (which is in the middle in gray color) with second fragment that I have, on the click of a "next button".
How can I "load" another fragment on button click in Android, using Kotlin?

[image: A picture of application, for better understanding of a problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If next button ID in the layout is "next" then you can make it like this:

```
val fragment = NextFragment()
next.setOnClickListener {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit()
    }
```

Where "fragmentContainer" (which is FrameLayout view) is the layout ID of the container where your fragments will be placed.

Comment: Thank you so much, Stack overflow's community is helpful really :)

Answer (score 1):

you can declare inline function like this

```
inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit) {
    val fragmentTransaction = beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.func()
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

use it  like ( this goes in your button click listener)

```
supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
    add(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment)
}
```